# FPDF cell text doesn't fit

Tags: php, zend-framework, fpdf

This is my PDF view. `$pdf->cell` text doesn't fit in the cell because is too big.

How can I make my text go to another line if it doesn't fit?

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting

Comment: Take a look at $pdf->MultiCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
        $pdf->Open();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetWidths(array(10, 15, 12, 14,25,17,35,15,15,20));
        srand(microtime()*1000000);

        $o=1;
        foreach ($finalData as $row) {

            if ($o == 1) {
                $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", "8");
            } elseif($o<>1) {
                $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "", "7");
            }
            $pdf->Row( $row);

            $o++;
        }


        $pdf->Output();
```

That's it! A beautifull table :)